# Terrain drawing Java

Tags: java, class, oop

I want to do produce a program that produces something like this (with the underscores flipped upside down for the top): [output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAyVx.png)

Note: I would prefer not to use UNICODE.

But instead, my output is this (with the underscores printing on the bottom): [output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFWlu.png)

```
public class Landscape {

    String terrainString;

    Landscape(){
        terrainString = "";
    }

    public void flat(int lengthOfFlatPortion){
        for (int count = 0; count < lengthOfFlatPortion; count++) {
            terrainString += "_";
        }
    }

    public void hill(int lengthOfHillTop){
        terrainString += "/";
        for (int count = 0; count < lengthOfHillTop; count++) {
            terrainString += "_";
        }
        terrainString += "\\";

    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.println(terrainString);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Landscape landscape = new Landscape();
        //BUILD Landscape Script
        landscape.flat(3);
        landscape.hill(4);
        landscape.flat(6);
        landscape.hill(1);
        landscape.flat(1);
        //END SCRIPT
        landscape.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `‾` ([unicode 203e](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/203e/index.htm)) instead of `_`.

Answer (score 0):

use `‾` char instead of `_`

```
public void hill(int lengthOfHillTop){
    terrainString += "/";
    for (int count = 0; count < lengthOfHillTop; count++) {
        terrainString += "‾";
    }
    terrainString += "\\";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I already said in the comments, use `‾` ([unicode 203e](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/203e/index.htm)) instead of `_` in method `hill(...)`.

To print a unicode character in java, prefix it with `\u`. So to print the overline, use the string `"\u203e"`.

If one does not want to use unicode characters, then you have to print a second line, above the first line. This means that this *hill*-line must be printed before the rest is printed. The line should only include blanks and underscores, and underscores should only printed where a flat hill surface is.

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/WNUg0P)

Comment: Thank you, but I want to avoid using unicode and possibly incorporating a second variable (ie. terrainString2) any suggestions as to how?

Comment: ... you should have stated so in the question. Yes, I have.